# Published Google Sheet - How to remove hover tooltip?

Tags: html, google-sheets, iframe

#### Background

I have a Google spreadsheet that contains multiple chart sheets.
I want to publish the entire spreadsheet and embed it in an HTML page (plain single HTML page. no other files.)

I have this simple HTML embedding simple published Google spreadsheet.

```html
<iframe height="400px" scrolling="no" src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSE-4lufoePc8SMq1r5o9K_uWE7Km9JiouogYBUJHVBo8Esnf4tImqdNUiCcWu_26AzwDUZCM_wS1Vs/pubhtml?widget=true&amp;headers=false" width="100%"></iframe>
```

#### Problem

I want to disable the tooltip-no-hover feature when the cursor is on some area of the chart (specifically one the bar itself).
As a matter of fact, I want to disable any user interaction with the chart.
However, the user still needs to be able to navigate between the sheets.

[image]

#### Failed attempts

I'm new in this area so likely my attempts/coding is senseless.

1. `<iframe enableInteractivity="False" ...`
2. `<iframe style="pointer-events: none;...` - did not allow to navigate between sheets.

Comment: Have you tried setting `tooltip:false`? @idanshmu

Comment: @ale13 not sure where and how I should define it exactly, but none of my tries worked.

Comment: How are you creating the chart? You created it simply from the spreadsheet?

Comment: I'm creating both the spreadsheet and the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

***Unfortunately, what you want cannot be achieved.***

According to the [Charts Service documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts):

> If you want to render charts in a web browser, use the Google Charts API instead.

The Google Charts Visualization API, however, allows you to modify the `tooltip`. But in order to do this, *you will have to create the chart programmatically.*

For this, you can try the example presented in the Quickstart [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start).

So after modifying the `options` parameter to this:

```
var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                       'width':400,
                       'height':300,
                       'tooltip': { 'trigger': 'selection' }};
```

This is how the chart will look like when hovering over the **Mushroom** part:

[image: chart created using Charts API]

You can include the code from the Quickstart mentioned above in an `HTML` file in Apps Script in order to create a web app. The only missing part is the `doGet` function, which can look something like this:

```
function doGet() {
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('QUICKSTART_HTML_FILE');
  return htmlOutput;
}
```

#### Reference

- [Google Charts Quick Start](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start);
- [Google Charts Tooltips](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content);
- [Apps Script Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web).

Comment: where is this code suppose to go? what is `dataTable` and how is it related to the iframe's src?

Comment: The code is supposed to go in your HTML and `dataTable` is `dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable()`.

Comment: how is the `datatable` related to the iframe's src? in the one-line HTML I provided, the data comes from the published sheet's URL (which I believe I'd need to keep it that way). in your suggestion, where does the data comes from?

Comment: I am sorry, I think I may have misunderstood you. So essentially you are not creating the chart programmatically at all?

Comment: Correct. The chart were created in google sheet itself. for the sake of the discussion, we may consider the the data/sheet as a closed box and just focus on the HTML (if that is even possible)